# How to show Mails sent using Mailkit in SentItems of Outlook

Tags: mailkit

I am able to **send mail using mailkit**. But only one thing is that those mails are not showing in **sentItems of outlook**. Can anyone guide me how to show those mails in sentItems folder. I think we can do the same **by using ImapClient of Mailkit** but can anyone provide the code snippet for the same.That will be more helpful. Also provide if there is any alternate option for the same.

Comment: Are you using Office 365 to send emails? Are you using the credentials of the same user who owns the sent items folder? Add more details to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes we are using Office 365 for sending mail. The credential is dynamic, we should capture the emailid from the token receive from AzureAD through redirect_uri and we do not know the password of that user.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient ()) {
    smtp.Connect ("smtp.host.com", port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
    smtp.Authenticate ("username", "password");
    smtp.Send (message);
    smtp.Disconnect (true);
}

using (var imap = new ImapClient ()) {
    imap.Connect ("host.com", port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
    imap.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    IMailFolder sent;

    if (imap.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.SpecialUse)) {
        sent = imap.GetFolder (SpecialFolder.Sent);
    } else {
        var personal = imap.GetFolder (imap.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
        sent = personal.GetSubfolder ("Sent Items");
    }

    // Append the message to the Sent Items folder.
    sent.Append (message, MessageFlags.Seen);

    imap.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had tried this and getting some error. I am using port 25 and getting the error that "syntax error in IMapServer greeting. Unexpected token : [atom : 220]" I doubt whether we can use port number 25 for making IMapClient connection.  Code I used ----> imapClient.Connect(hostname, 25,false);

Comment: Port 25 is only for SMTP. IMAP is on port 143 or 993. You really need to check with your provider to get the right info.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will get this checked.